# How 32bit architecture is differ from 64bit architecture mainly in form of app speed and memory management?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cpu-architecture

As per my knowledge, OS architecture is generally used to speed up our OS and adding new features with higher `memory management` but in `IOS` i am little bit confuse regarding architecture which we generally set in our app is as below

**Architectures** - `Standard Architecture (armv7,arm64)` `Valid Architectures - armv7,arm64,armv7s`.

Due to this, we are getting many warnings related to datatypes size and conversation because `64-bit architecture` is the use of `processors` that have `datapath widths`, `integer size`, and `memory address widths` of `64 bits`.

so my question is I want to understand what mechanism will work behind this while I generating `IPA` file for `32 bit` supported architecture or `64 bit` architecture *(I know now after `XCode-6` we will only build our app with 64-bit architecture with `bitcode` enabled in our app for thining our app size)*

Can anyone help me with this to understand `architecture` mechanism, especially in IOS?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- Original Link: http://iossupportmatrix.com/

To add on to what Avi said, I hope this picture will give you a better understanding of how OS are evolving. The more right you go, the more the OS can handle information (it can handle more RAM) and some application require more RAM to run. I wish I could give you more specific information about this but I wouldn't want to say something wrong.

Comment: Cedric can you explain in detail regarding above answer ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two architecture settings in an iOS project:

- Architectures
- Valid Architectures

The list of Valid Architectures constrains the possible values in the Architectures list.

When building for debugging on a device, Xcode will only build for the architecture of the target device (which may be x86, for the simulator).  If the target device is a 32bit architecture, you'll get a 32-bit build.

When building for some kind of release (ad-hoc or App Store), Xcode will build for all the architectures listed in the build setting's Architecture list.  The app binary, along with any dynamically-loaded frameworks will have a slice for each architecture.

Comment: Yes Avi you are right regarding architecture setting but what my question is what is the difference between both of them and why we are setting armv7,arm64,armv7s for 64 bit architecture ?

Comment: Between both of what?  And why do you think you're setting armv7 and armv7s for 64bit architectures?